# unwanted spam urls in ajax request

Tags: spam, spam-prevention

While checking any website's ajax requests, I found some spam urls as shown below.

Why they sudden came?

Is it spam?

How do I remove this from ajax request?

for example :

http://www.superfish.com/ws/tpl/ads.tpl?version=14.07.20.7

http://www.superfish.com/ws/getUD.action?dlsource=Diigoscreenshot&userId=3856ac02-983a-b6e1-f56b-2356e3a28f00-80b&ver=14.07.20.7&distributor=Diigo

See below image :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of Awesome screenshot add-on.
It searches for some similar products through requests.

To disable these requests Go To Options.
There is a option for "Enable similar product search powered by Superfish " in settings

Uncheck it and everything works as expected.